# How to exclude these url paths in chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension, match, manifest

I currently use this to run my extension only in `https://www.imdb.com/title/movieid/` pages.
I dont want it to run in any other sub paths

```json
{
    "matches": ["*://*.imdb.com/title/*/*"],
    "exclude_globs": ["*://*.imdb.com/title/*/*/"],
    "js": ["src/imdb/imdb.js"]
}
```

these urls "https://www.imdb.com/title/movieid/fullcredits", "https://www.imdb.com/title/movieid/videogallery" bypasses the above match

Comment: Try `exclude_matches`. Also remove the last `/`